# Conditional global variable in Golang

Tags: go, conditional-statements, conditional-compilation

I have a configuration constant.

```
const connectionIsSerial = false // Or maybe true...
```

And a type definition:

```
type connection struct {
    connected bool
    mutex     sync.Mutex
    handler *mb.RTUOverTCPClientHandler // Option A - For TCP handler.
    //handler * mb.RTUClientHandler     // Option B - For serial handler.
}
```

And a global variable to store the connection:

```
var conn connection
```

Both types of handler have similar methods. I want to be able to **conditionally define the above `type connection` at compile time**, similarly to what you would do with `#ifdef` preprocessor directives in C.

The only solution I have found so far is to do something like:

```
type connection struct {
    connected bool
    mutex     sync.Mutex
    handler   any
}
```

And then conditionally assert the type every time the handler is called. This is a pain and looks ugly too.
I know that Go is very different, but I am sure some elegant solution exists out there... Any advice?

Comment: You could use build constraints to solve this at build time (you have to pass build tags to the go tool), or simply use an interface type which deals with this at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, however no way to do this starting from a go constant, right? In my example, reading the value of the constant `connectionIsSerial`.

Comment: No builtin solution for that, but you could have a script that parses this out of a file and passes it as a build tag.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I guess at that point would be better to move all the configuration constants out as well. It sounds messy... Cheers